# Should questions which will have exactly the same answers be marked as duplicates?

Tags: support, specific-question, exact-duplicates

[**Question A**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23476/4732)

It asks "Which scripture is the source of a verse A?"

[**Question B**:](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20043/4732)

This question asks "Which scripture is the source of a verse B and who composed it?"

Now, verse A and B both are part of a same Stotra, with verse A the 1st verse and verse B the 5th verse of a [Saraswati Storam](http://greenmesg.org/stotras/saraswati/saraswati_stotram.php) (a Hymn), which was composed by Agastya Muni.

So, both these questions will have the same answer, if the Stotra is at all part of some scriptures. (the author part is already answered by me under Q- B, and the OP of Q-A is not asking about author at all)

The answer of both the questions will be just one viz-something like " Yes, it's part of XYZ Purana or some other scripture"

Question: So should they be considered as duplicates? (Question A should be marked as a duplicate of Question B)

**UPDATE:**

The answer given uses the following questions as examples:

> Who is the father of Kumara Swamy and Ganesha?
>
> Who is the husband of Parvati Devi?

Now, these questions are entirely different questions. None can mark them as duplicates.

In this case, however, both the questions are "exactly" the same. The question basically is:

"In which scripture is found Agastya Krutha Saraswati Stotram?"

Assume, there is a Stotram comprised of 50 verses. Are we going to allow 50 such different questions that are just asking, separately, "What is the source of verse 1 to 50?"

Comment: The questions are different. It is like what is 5+3? and 6+2. They have the same answers but the questions are different. So, they can't be closed.  Read [this](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2760/48608) answer from a sister site meta.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma if 2 different Qns have similar potential answers then they are possible duplicates: Refer the quoted [text here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1105/1049). Now there are special cases: Q1 "Who is Subhadra's husband"? Q2 "Who was told Gita by Krishna?". Both answers are "Arjuna". Here Q1 & Q2 are Not duplicates. But if any answer of Q1 covers Q2 as well, then they are duplicates.

Comment: ""In which scripture is found Agastya Krutha Saraswati Stotram?"" Nope. The question is Which scripture has the shloka not the stotram because the questioners do not know that it is a part of Agastya kruta stotram.

Comment: Is this related to unethical rep earning as well ?

Comment: That is discussed [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/752/277).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules to be followed while answering two similar questions?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/707/what-are-the-rules-to-be-followed-while-answering-two-similar-questions). According to that post, Question A and B are duplicates.

Comment: Yes, it is @RakeshJoshi See this post: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/is-it-ethical-to-earn-reputation-by-copying-contents-from-own-others-duplicates

Answer (score 3):

When the questions are asking the same or expressing the same meaning with different words and gives the same answer, they can be closed as duplicates.

But here, the questions and verses asked are different. Two questions are asking two different veres. Even though the answer is the same stotra, they can't be closed as exact duplicates. For example, consider this question:

> 1. Who is the father of Kumara Swamy and Ganesha?
> 2. Who is the husband of Parvati Devi?

No doubt, the answer to both the questions is Shiva but they are **not duplicate questions**.

[An answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2760/48608) from a sister meta site address a similar query.

> In general, it is incorrect to dupe close based on the answer. Just because two questions have the same answer does not mean that they are the same question.

Only exception to this rule are canonical questions which are always answered in the same way without a detailed explanation or introduction. For example "Why is this user suspended?". So, those questions can be closed as duplicates.

---

The edit made by the author of the [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23476/5212) makes clearer why they are not duplicates.

> People trying to mark the question as a duplicate kindly note the so called Agastya Stotra that is the answer in the other question is NOT the only source of this verse. No point linking this to that since this particular prayer is found in multiple texts including the Bhavabhuti Subhashita.

So, they are **not duplicates** because the stotra is not the only source. It is found in many other documents.

Comment: Your linked meta post's answer was greatly written and accurate. Users of this site should learn from linked post :)

Comment: You have completely ignored the fact that the Qs also are almost similar or even exactly similar. The examples that you're giving in the answer are not relevant here. Those are completely different Qs.

Comment: @Rickross Sure.. you need a reason for a disagreement. The questions I gave are different and not duplicates at all. When a user wants to find father of Ganesha and sees a duplicate linking who is Parvati's husband? How will the closure help? We should see the usefulness for the future users. The questions I linked are relevant and also the examples I gave are very much relevant.